# EXTjs gridfilter: How to clearfilter without reloading store?

Tags: extjs

In extjs GridFilters, is there a way to clear the filters without reloading the store?
This is the rquirement:
There is a grid(#1) and another grid(#2) below the grid. The grid(#1) has a list of ids, and when a particular id is clicked, the grid(#2) is popualted with a list of records that belong to that id.
And example might be:grid#1: list of all maangers
grid#2: list of all employees for a particular maanger.

Grid #2 has a filter: on employee name.

The rqmt is: When a selection is changed in grid#1, clear all the old filters, but do not relaod the store for grid #2 as grid#2 store will be loaded through another function.

Please let me know how I can help by providing more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some Firebug stepping, I found this works quite well.

```
var store = this.getStore();
store.remoteFilter = false;
store.clearFilter();
store.remoteFilter = true;
store.filter(...);
```

`remoteFilter` does not seem to be a documented property, but it will suspend xhr calls while it's set to `false`.

When you set `remoteFilter` to false, when `clearFilter()` is called, the `load()` function is stepped over.

Comment: Thanks! Or you can directly remove all items in the filters by calling `store.filters.clear();` :)

Comment: @Han your comment should be an answer, and I believe it is the most correct one as `store.filters.clear()` does not cause a reload unlike `store.clearFilter()` which does.

Comment: Actually the comment from @Jone Polvora to an answer below suggesting `store.clearFilter(true)` seems to be a bit better as it is mentioned in the [Sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-clearFilter)

Answer (score 0):

The clearFilters() method available with GridFilter class should be able to clear the filters. Did you give it a try? Also, when does the grid#2 get loaded? according to your first para, when the user select a manager the employees are listed. But in the second para where you stated your requirement, you said the grid#2 is loaded through another function!.. no clear with that though.

Comment: Thank you. when user selects a manager, the 'anotehr function' is called and it loads the store. So we need to disable the store load that fires on clearfilters(). Can you give ideas on how to do this?i.e. fire clearfitlers() without reload store

Answer (score 0):

have you tried temporarily suspending the events on the grid? 
grid.suspendEvents();
grid.doYourMagic();
grid.resumeEvents();

reloading of the store is most likely triggered by an event anyway.

Comment: `store.clearFilters()` causes an HTTP request regardless of whether `store.suspendEvents()` has been called or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue but not with a Grid but with a DataView, however, this might apply equally to your case. I initially tried:

```
var store = this.getStore();
store.suspendEvents();
store.clearFilter();
store.resumeEvents();
store.filter(...);
```

this didn't work—still 2 HTTP requests were made, once for `clearFilter()`, once for `filter(...)`.

However, the following works:

```
var store = this.getStore();
store.getProxy().extraParams['q'] = keywords;
store.load();
```

Comment: store.clearFilter(true) will do a silent clearing... silent means no requests to the server.

Comment: @Jone this comment should be an answer.