# Extjs skip store load conditionally

Tags: extjs

This question is related to another question:
[EXTjs gridfilter: How to clearfilter without reloading store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011042/extjs-gridfilter-how-to-clearfilter-without-reloading-store)

My thinking is:

If there is 1 store and there are two functions `(f1)` and `(f2)` and both call `store.load()`.

Both `f1` and `f2` will be called and the order is not guaranteed. Is there a way for f1 to check if store has already been loaded by `f2`(and vice versa) and if loaded, skip the `store.load` command for `f1`.

What I am looking for is a method like:

```
 f1() {
     if (!store.isLoadedAsPartOfThisRequest() //true/false){
         store.load(params);
     }
 }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: could you use `store.getCount()` to see if the store has any records in it before loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *store.getCount()* is certainly a crude solution and creates inaccuracies if the loaded records happen to be none.

Sencha Support presented a [solution](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?91923-How-to-check-datastore-is-loaded&p=436882&viewfull=1#post436882):

*'Check Store for lastOptions, if that exists then your Store has loaded at least once.'*

It seems that *lastOptions* is no longer part of ExtJS 4.1. As a workaround, one can include and set an "isLoaded" boolean as part of a Store load override.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on the issue:
have two boolean variables for each store. Both will be initially set to false (Meaning the store is not loaded).

Now, both the stores will have a listener method for the 'load' event. The listener method will simply set the boolean variable if the store is loaded.

So, in your f1 and f2, you will check for the boolean values call reload. At the same time you will have find where and when you will set the boolean variables to false again.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. Why do we need 2 booleans? 1 will not do?