# Extjs Grid Panel Filter - Clear filters only in one column

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

This question ([EXTjs gridfilter: How to clearfilter without reloading store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011042/extjs-gridfilter-how-to-clearfilter-without-reloading-store)) shows how to clear all the filters on the entire grid.

Is there a way to clear only the filters in a specific column? For example, if I have a column with a list filter that has 20 options and I select 8 of them, I'd like a button that will uncheck all of those, but leave any other filters I've selected to remain in tact.

The 'size' column on this demo is a good example of what the filtering looks like: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the [`setActive`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.filter.Filter-method-setActive) method of the filter.

And here's how you can get a reference to this filter:

```
// FiltersFeature adds a filters property to the grid it is bound to
grid.filters.getFilter('size').setActive(false)
```

**Edit:** How to uncheck all boxes

```
var filter = grid.filters.getFilter('size');
filter.menu.items.each(function(checkbox) {
    // The second argument suppress the check event in order to prevent
    // unexpected behaviour, like the filter reenabling itself and trying
    // to update the store several times in a row
    checkbox.setChecked(false, true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great. Do you know how to make it so that the boxes that were checked actually show up as unchecked. The functionality is there, it just doesn't show it on the actual boxes. If you go to select a new filter, you still have to uncheck all those boxes.

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing built in for that. I've added some code to show you how it can be done in my answer.